# Azure HDInsight chained Mapreduce : Input path does not exist

Tags: azure, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, azure-hdinsight

So my map reduce functions run fine on my local VM, but on Azure it gives me `Input path not found` error. I have two sets of mapper & reducer functions, the output from the first reducer goes into a temp folder that is the input to the second mapper.

```
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));

    FileSystem.get(conf).delete(new Path("file:///tmp/inter/"),true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("file:///tmp/inter/"));
    boolean complete = job.waitForCompletion(true);

    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf, "Q4a");
    job2.setJarByClass(Q4a.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper2.class);
    job2.setCombinerClass(CountReducer2.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(CountReducer2.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

//    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path("file:///tmp/inter/part*"));
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path("file:///tmp/inter/"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

[image]

The first mapper & reducer execute fully, and then the error is thrown.
Line 58 is the last line in the pasted code, but I believe the error is from the temp input path? Do I need to refer to temp files in a different manner in Azure? Any help is much appreciated, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just solved this. Looks like HDInsight does not support the folder structure I specified. I changed the path to simply "out" instead of "file:///tmp/inter" and it worked.

Comment: You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT SO only allows it after 2 days of posting so I'm waiting :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please do remember to mark as answer after 2 days.